# Javascript validation is not validating

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi there I'm trying to make my JS validate my contact form with the following required...

Trying to do it with XHTML1.0

Comment: Could you give us your HTML as well? And why are you using xhtml? And what validation rules are there?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Hi there Nate, my HTML is in JSFIDDLE. There's no real reason for using it.

Comment: there are all reasons to post your html your given ids are worth confirming if you are using right ones in your functions

Comment: @M.chaudhry HTML has just been added

Answer (score 0):

This code has error:

> email is not defined
>   on line:

```
    var valid = email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]){1,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/);
```

and this html code is incorrect ;p

```
<input id="text" type="email" />
```

I think you mean:

```
 <input id="email" type="text" />
```

Comment: HTML5 allows for email type input.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of problems, the first step to debugging is to open the developer console (F12) and observe the error messages.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN56E/)

Changes:

- Removed `var valid = email.match....` which is causing an error and the return value is never used.
- Change jsfiddle to run in `<head>` not onload because you have inline event handlers, which need the functions to be in the global scope, in order to be accessible.
- Moved all of the code that deals with elements into the `onload` function, because it is trying to access DOM elements before they are even rendered.
- Changed the phone input ID from `text1` to `phone`.
- Removed the line that hides the phone number input because it makes no sense.

Updated code:

```
function elem(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};


window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector("#RadioGroup1_0").click();

    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.onsubmit = function (e) {
        var rules = [
            ['first-name', elem('first-name').value.length > 0],
            ['last-name', elem('last-name').value.length > 0],
            ['phone', elem('phone').value.length > 0 && /^(\+\d{1,2})?[\d ()-]+$/.test(elem('phone').value)]
        ];

        function alpha(e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            if (!rules[i][1]) {
                var parent = elem(rules[i][0]).parentNode,
                    message = 'Please check your ' + (parent.textContent || parent.innerText).replace(/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/, '$1').slice(0, -1).toLowerCase() + '.';

                alert(message);

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    };
}


function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        } else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode === 8)) return true;
        else return false;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}


var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
function IsNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
    //document.getElementById("phone").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hand, but is it possible to make it innerHTML not alert? To display the error next to the field itself? Cheers

Comment: Yes it is possible, just add a span next to the input (like you already have with the phone) and replace the alert with `x.innerHTML = message`.

Comment: I can't seem to get it work? Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" onkeypress="return validateNumbers(event);"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Enabled="false" ForeColor="Red" ClientIDMode="Static" ErrorMessage="Input valid email address!">
```

```
     And in javascript use like below
```

ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('txtEmail'), true);